# Using SharedPreferences between activities to retrieve data to unlock button

Tags: android

there is something i had issue in regarding to my buttons. I am creating an Android Game App. So far, i managed to be able to unlock the next level based on the score requirement needed on Level 1 to unlock Level 2. The problem is after i go back the page from Level 2 to the Level Selection Page, or go to some other pages. Level 2 button suddenly became **lock** again. I know i will need SharedPreferences in order to save all the status of my app so Level 2 button will remain unlock forever unless the App is uninstalled. Anyone can be able to help? Here is the code:

DBHelper.java

```
public class DBHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {
    private static final String TAG = "Database";
    private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;
    private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "Level";
    private static final String USERTABLE = "USER_INFO";
    private static final String KEY_ID = "id";
    private static final String LEVEL1 = "LEVEL1";
    private static final String LEVEL2 = "LEVEL2";

    private static final String CREATE_TABLE_USER = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS "
            + USERTABLE + "(" + KEY_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY," + LEVEL1 + " TEXT,"
            + LEVEL2 + " TEXT"+");";

    private static final String SQL_DELETE_ENTRIES =
            "DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + USERTABLE;

    public DBHelper(Context context) {
        super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        Log.e(TAG,"Inside onCreate: creating table");
        db.execSQL(CREATE_TABLE_USER);
    }

    //to save score in db according to the level
    public void saveData(int level,String score){
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        ContentValues data = new ContentValues();
        switch(level){
            case 1:
                data.put(LEVEL1, score);
                break;
            case 2:
                data.put(LEVEL2,score);
                break;
        }
        db.insert(USERTABLE,null,data);
        db.close();
    }


    //to get score from db
    //you can modify this function if you want to get score for a specific level
    public HashMap<String,String> getData(){
        HashMap<String,String> scoreMap = new HashMap<>();
        String selectQuery = "SELECT  * FROM " + USERTABLE ;
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(selectQuery, null);
        if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
            do {

                scoreMap.put(LEVEL1, "5");
                scoreMap.put(LEVEL2,cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(LEVEL2)));
            } while (cursor.moveToNext());
        }
        cursor.close();
        return scoreMap;

    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
        Log.e(TAG,"Inside onUpgrade");
        db.execSQL(SQL_DELETE_ENTRIES);
        onCreate(db);
    }
}
```

Levelpage.java

```
@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_level_page);
        getSupportActionBar().hide();

        final MediaPlayer clickSound = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.click2);
        setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);

        btnBack = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonBack);
        btnInfo = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonInfo);
        btnLevel1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
        btnLevel2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button2);
        btnLevel3 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button3);
        btnLevel4 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button4);
        btnLevel5 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button5);
        btnLevel6 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button6);
        btnLevel7 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button7);
        btnLevel8 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button8);
        btnLevel9 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button9);
        btnLevel10 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button10);
        btnLevel11 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button11);
        btnLevel12 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button12);
        btnLevel13 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button13);

        DBHelper db = new DBHelper(LevelPage.this);
        db.saveData(2,"5");
        HashMap<String,String> data = db.getData();
        String level1Score = data.get("LEVEL1");

        btnLevel1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                clickSound.start();
                Intent intent = new Intent(LevelPage.this, Level1.class);
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        });


        Intent i = getIntent();
        score = i.getIntExtra("SCORE",0);
        if (score == 5 && level1Score.equals("5")) {
        btnLevel2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                    clickSound.start();
                    Intent intent = new Intent(LevelPage.this, Level2.class);
                    startActivity(intent);
                    btnLevel2.setEnabled(true);
                }
            });

        } else {
            btnLevel2.setEnabled(false);
        }

        Intent i2 = getIntent();
        int score2 = i2.getIntExtra("SCORE2", 0);
        if (score2 == 30) {
            btnLevel3.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    clickSound.start();
                    Intent intent = new Intent(LevelPage.this, Level3.class);
                    startActivity(intent);
                    btnLevel3.setEnabled(true);
                }
            });
        } else {
            btnLevel3.setEnabled(false);
        }

        btnBack.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                finish();
            }
        });

        btnInfo.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                clickSound.start();
                Intent intent = new Intent(LevelPage.this, InfoPage.class);
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        });

    }

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        finish();
    }


}
```

Comment: SharedPreference is a good for maintaining sessions and you can use that but once the user has unlocked the level2 and you want it unlocked till app uninstalls I'll recommend you to use Sqlite db. that will be best for your case

Comment: Oh hi, its you.  Anyway, if that is the case. Alright then. i am not sure how i can do SQLite db in here.  I only recently learn the extreme basic so i dont know how to implement on my app in this case.

Comment: Maybe i will find a solution first to do SQLite db in my case. It would great if you have time to spend on helping me. Very appreciated as always but hope it will not be a  burden for you.

Comment: you need to do some small changes in your code this part DBHelper db = new DBHelper(LevelPage.this);
        db.saveData(2,"5");
you need to put when when score is 5 and you're going from level1 to level2

Comment: and in LevelActivity :
DBHelper db = new DBHelper(LevelPage.this);
HashMap<String,String> data = db.getData();
        String level2Score = data.get("LEVEL2");
if(level2Score.equals(5)){
//enable level2 button
}

then it'll be always enabled

Comment: Wait, i thought its suppose to be (1,"5")? Because in level 1, i need score 5 point to unlock level 5. Also, the part about need put db = new DBHelper(LevelPage.this); db.saveData(2,"5") when score is 5 and you're going from level1 to level2. I not sure what you mean. Am i suppose to put those 2 in Level 1 Page?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/146360/discussion-between-mobile-developer-and-sumit).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a dbHelper class like this

```
public class DatabaseNew extends SQLiteOpenHelper {
private static final String TAG = "DataBase";

public DatabaseNew(Context context){
    super(context,DATABASE_NAME,null,DATABASE_VERSION);
}
private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;
private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "Module1";
private static final String USERTABLE = "USER_INFO";
private static final String KEY_ID = "id";
private static final String LEVEL1 = "LEVEL1";
private static final String LEVEL2 = "LEVEL2";

private static final String CREATE_TABLE_USER = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS "
        + USERTABLE + "(" + KEY_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY," + LEVEL1 + " TEXT,"
        + LEVEL2 + " TEXT"+");";

private static final String SQL_DELETE_ENTRIES =
        "DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + USERTABLE;

@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
    Log.e(TAG,"Inside onCreate: creating table");
    db.execSQL(CREATE_TABLE_USER);
}

//to save score in db according to the level
public void saveData(int level,String score){
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    ContentValues data = new ContentValues();
    switch(level){
    case 1:
    data.put(LEVEL1,score);
    break:
    case 2:
    data.put(LEVEL2,score);
    break;
    }
    db.insert(USERTABLE,null,data);
    db.close();
}

//to get score from db
//you can modify this function if you want to get score for a specific level
public HashMap<String,String> getData(){
    HashMap<String,String> scoreMap = new HashMap<>();
    String selectQuery = "SELECT  * FROM " + USERTABLE ;
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(selectQuery, null);
    if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
        do {

            scoreMap.put(LEVEL1,cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(LEVEL1)));
            scoreMap.put(LEVEL2,cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(LEVEL2)));
        } while (cursor.moveToNext());
    }
    cursor.close();
    return scoreMap;

}

@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
    Log.e(TAG,"Inside onUpgrade");
    db.execSQL(SQL_DELETE_ENTRIES);
    onCreate(db);
}
}
```

then inside your activity

```
    //Initializing the db
    DatabaseNew db = new DatabaseNew(this);

    //sending level and its score
    db.saveData(level,level score);

    //to retrieve data from data base
    HashMap<String,String> data = db.getData();
    String level1Score = data.get("LEVEL1");
    String level2Score = data.get("LEVEL2");

    // now you can use these score however you like
```

I have created the db for two levels you can modify it according to the number of levels you have.

Comment: Wow, i can't believe you spend your time to do the code for me. I really am truly grateful. I will take the time to slowly learn the code your provide and do it. Will tell you if it work. Thank you very, very much again. If possible, i really hope i could meet you in person and give you a meal as a thanks.

Comment: No problem buddy if it works for you just accept it as a answer that will be enough :)

Comment: There is something wrong with the return scoreMap. It says about incompatible types.

Comment: Oh now i see. I was wondering what is the List really about haha

Comment: The 2nd part of the code regarding about calling from DBHelper or known as DatabaseNew, i tried to put in the code but it does not seem to work. i not sure which part i did wrong. May i know an example on how you can do that? Also, the code should be put in Level Selection Page right?

Comment: I put my code above. You may check to see what went wrong

Comment: Sorry, i deleted my post which answer my question. So i re-edit my initial post on the above. So you can continue check from there.

Comment: There is a little problem i am facing now. When i play level 2 to get 35 score, level 3 is unlock. But, level 2 is suddenly lock. And even if i replay level 1 to unlock level 2, level 3 will be lock. I do not know what is the problem now. I did the same codes and everything for Level 2 just like for Level 1.

Comment: you might have used condition if(score.equals(5)) to unlock.check that or share the code where you're unlocking level2 and level3 buttons

Comment: Hi sumit, i am back to focus on my game app project. Right now, i am still facing the issue that i mention above. I cannot be able to solve the issue